# Angular Material md dialog locals giving unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I am trying to pass a variable with the md dialog service but it is giving me unknown provider error for the md dialog service

What I have tried so far is as follows -

```
$mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'SignInModalController',
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/signin_modal.html',
                targetEvent: ev,
                size: 'sm',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                locals: {
                    "login_cookies": cookies
                }
            })
```

I am trying to pass this locals object to the sign in modal controller which has the following code - >

```
app.controller('SignInModalController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$mdDialog', 'Auth', '$mdToast', 'login_cookies',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $mdDialog, Auth, $mdToast, login_cookies) {
```

and I am getting the following error message in console after this - >

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: login_cookiesProvider <- login_cookies <- SignInModalController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=login_cookiesProvider%20%3C-%20login_cookies%20%3C-%20SignInModalController
```

Also the sign in modal controller file is lazily loaded during the initial bootstrapping of angular app like this - >

```
.state('app', {
                        abstract: true,
                        url: '/app?feedback',
                        views: {
                            '': {
                                templateUrl: 'views/layout.html'
                            },
                            'aside': {
                                templateUrl: 'views/aside.html'
                            },
                            'content': {
                                templateUrl: 'views/content.html'
                            }
                        },
                        resolve: load([
                            'scripts/google_analytics.js',
                            'scripts/controllers/app/aside.js',
                            'scripts/controllers/app/navbar.js',
                            'scripts/controllers/app/reach_us.js',
                            'scripts/controllers/app/labs/filter.ctrl.js',
                            'scripts/controllers/app/signin_modal.js',
                            'scripts/controllers/app/feedback.js'])
                    })
```

What other things should I check in order to resolve this error ?

### UPDATE

On setting a breakpoint in the dialog controller as soon as I open the dialog I get the following result -

[image: debug]

As you can see the passed array (`list_cookies`) does have a value and yet in the console I am getting this error -

[image: console]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotation marks: `locals: { login_cookies: cookies }`?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help either

Comment: One of our dependencies in your SignInModalController is login_cookies. Have you declared this elsewhere in your application? That is what the unknown provider message is complaining about.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Yeah, I had the same controller declared in two states with different parameters, so when the second controller was getting registered, it was throwing error

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on deadman's latest comment, this is more of follow up on how the issue was identified/solved by him.

Try remove ng-controller in the md-dialog tag.  I think that is because when you call $mdDialog.show, you passed in the providers, in this case, the locals.  However, if you have ng-controller in the md-dialog tag, it is declared without the context of the the locals.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is you want to inject `dialogLocals` into your `SignInModalController` and then access the `login_cookies` as `dialogLocals.login_cookies`.

So change:

```
app.controller('SignInModalController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$mdDialog', 'Auth', '$mdToast', 'login_cookies', function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $mdDialog, Auth, $mdToast, login_cookies) {
```

To:

```
app.controller('SignInModalController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$mdDialog', 'Auth', '$mdToast', 'dialogLocals', function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $mdDialog, Auth, $mdToast, dialogLocals) {
```

Then access from your `SignInModalController` as:

```
dialogLocals.login_cookies
```

Comment: When i try as your answer, i get 
```Unknown provider: dialogLocalsProvider <- dialogLocals <- myController```
error. Also i couldn't find anything related to your answer [in the docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog). Is it a version issue? If so, please state your version and if possible share the documentation link.